# Expectation of $\max(X-K,0)$

Tags: probability

How are you supposed to derive the expectation of $\max(X-K,0)$ where $X\sim N(\mu;\sigma^2)$ using integration

$$E\left[ \left( X-K\right) ^{+}\right] =\int ^{\infty }_{K}\left( \int ^{\infty }_{x}f\left( t\right) dt\right) dx$$

$$\int ^{\infty }_{K}\dfrac {1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}\int ^{\infty }_{x} \exp\left( -(t-\mu \right) ^{2}/2\sigma ^{2}dt$$

$$u=\dfrac {1}{\sqrt {2\pi }\sigma }\int ^{\infty }_{x}\exp\left( -(t-\mu \right) ^{2}/2\sigma ^{2}\,dt$$

$$du=\dfrac {-1}{\sqrt {2\pi }\sigma }\exp\left( -\left( x-\mu \right) ^{2}/2\sigma ^{2}\right)$$

$v=x,\quad dv=dx$

And with this set up you should use the integration by parts formula:

$$\int u\,dv=uv-\int du\,v$$

To get:

$$\dfrac {-K}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}\int ^{\infty }_{K}\exp\left( -\left( t-\mu \right) ^{2}/2\sigma ^{2}\right) dt + \dfrac {1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}\int ^{\infty }_{K}t\exp\left( -\left( t-\mu \right) ^{2}/2\sigma ^{2}\right) \,dt$$

Answer (score 5):

If I have done my computations correctly, 
$${\rm E}[\max\{X-K,0\}] = \int_{x=K}^\infty (x-K) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} \, dx.$$  With the substitution $u = (x-\mu)/\sigma$, $du = 1/\sigma \, dx$, we obtain $$\begin{align*} {\rm E}[\max\{X-K,0\}] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{u=(K-\mu)/\sigma}^\infty (\sigma u + \mu-K) e^{-u^2/2} \, du \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \biggl( \sigma \int_{u=L}^\infty u e^{-u^2/2} \, du + (\mu - K) \int_{u=L}^\infty e^{-u^2/2} \, du \biggr).\end{align*}$$  The first integral can be evaluated with a simple substitution of $v = u^2/2$, whereas the second integral is the survival function of the standard normal distribution at $u = L = (K-\mu)/\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you very much heropup! Cheers